# JSON Serializing confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, api

I'm simply building a test Web API that takes a JSON payload and will simply send back the data in the array portion from my MVC Controller.

This is my current JSON string when serialized by my populated classes:

```
{"JobList":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Dave","Age":23,"StartDate":"10/23/2013 6:22:50 AM","JobTitle":"Developer"},{"ID":2,"Name":"John","Age":44,"StartDate":"10/23/2013 6:22:50 AM","JobTitle":"QA"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Dave","Age":23,"StartDate":"10/23/2013 6:22:50 AM","JobTitle":"Senior Developer"}]}
```

This is the object used to create this JSON:

```
var jobList = new JobsList()
        {
            JobList = new List<Jobs>()
            {
                new Jobs()
                {
                    Age = 23,
                    ID = 1,
                    Name = "Dave",
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                    JobTitle = "Developer"
                },
                new Jobs()
                {
                    Age = 44,
                    ID = 2,
                    Name = "John",
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                    JobTitle = "QA"
                },
                new Jobs()
                {
                    Age = 23,
                    ID = 3,
                    Name = "Dave",
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                    JobTitle = "Senior Developer"
                }
            }

        };
```

Here are my individual classes:

JobsList Class:

```
public class JobsList:IJobList
{
    #region IJobList Members

    public List<Jobs> JobList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Jobs Class:

```
public class Jobs:Interfaces.IJobs
{

    #region IJobs Members

    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StartDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string JobTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I convert my JSON to produce classes through the use of JSON2Csharp the classes are produced as shown:

```
public class JobList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<JobList> JobList { get; set; }
}
```

This to me seems incorrect. Can anyone explain why I am not getting a 'Jobs' node in my JSON set to the JobsList array? And why do the generated JSON2CSharp classes map my 'Jobs' class as a JobList class?

Comment: If you already have the classes needed to (de)serialize the json, why are you using JSON2Csharp?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it was out of interest more than anything, but when the produced classes seemed different to mine - the JSON string is also slightly different to what I was expecting - I couldn't understand why it was mapping that way.

Comment: From what I can tell, this looks more like a problem with JSON2Csharp's ability to parse out lists. Really, as long as your program can serialize/deserialize your JSON, you should be fine. (also, if JSON2CSharp *did* pick up your jobs node, it would probably be called something like "ChildObject," since it can't know the name of your class from that serialized JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's because deserializer (in this case, JSON2CSharp) doesn't know what you named your original classes. Or how you structured them, for that matter. It doesn't know about any of that stuff you posted below "my current JSON string."

When you hand it that JSON object, that's all the information it is working with. So, it can tell that there's some sort of object (which it calls "RootObject"), which has an array of objects called "JobList". So it called the class "JobList". It had a choice there -- it could have simply called the list "JobList" and named the object something else... but it has no way of knowing that it was originally from an object named "Jobs", because that's not in the JSON. A different deserializer may have done it differently.

I am not familiar with JSON2CSharp specifically, so I don't know if it can do this, but there are frameworks that, given the object definition, can parse a JSON string with consistently named fields and load it into that object. For example, with Json.NET, you can do something like this:

```
JobsList jobList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobsList>(JsonString);
```